Подскажите в чем проблема с алиасами ts-jest
имеется проект собранный по fsd, на каждом уровне есть index.ts который реэкспортит файлы и не могу понять почему не работают алиасы в тестах - подскажите, пжлста
webpack
alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },

tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
}

jest.config.json
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },

импорт в компоненте
import { TEXT_STYLE } from '@/shared';

версия
 "ts-jest": "24.3.0",


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
